# Inheriting height of a child node (IMG inside A)

Tags: css

I have a fancy CSS on my `<a>` tags. Putting an `<img>` inside of a link makes the image stick outside of the `<a>` block, even though it's still clickable, it looks stupid.

Changing `<a>` to `display:block`, or `float:left` fixes this, but has an undesirable *not*-side effect.

How can I overcome this?

http://jsfiddle.net/z5gdA/2/

Comment: What's the desired effect? The image is rendered as expected: The padding property at the anchor adds a small gap between the anchor's bound. The `height:3em` property expands the image.

Comment: Why was this migrated from webmasters? [another question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10211/how-to-adsense-report-issue-with-highlight-blackout-screenshot) of mine was moved TO webmasters.

Comment: "Please note that if your question is about detailed HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding, it might be a better fit on Stack Overflow." ~[webmasters FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inline-block will solve the problem, but it wont work with IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/dbugger/z5gdA/3/

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `<a>` to `display: inline-block`.  That should work in most browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Use pixels for your image height, not "em".

Comment: How would this fix the problem?

Comment: I did and for me the image is still outside of the a? http://jsfiddle.net/z5gdA/4/

Comment: Works for me: img.big { height:15px }

Comment: Yes, this sort of solves it. Actually, the more times I read the question the less I understand the question. If he wants to make the image smaller, then yes, this works. If he wants to crop it, it doesn't. Personally I think vertical-align: middle looks really neat. :)

Comment: I like background images myself :)

Comment: You guys are freaking me out. The desired result is what apparently `inline-block` does. I used 3em to guarantee that the image is taller than text.