# wrapping block elements with <a>

Tags: css, html

as i read around the web, it's a valid html5 practice to wrap block elements inside `<a>` elements. i have a problem though.

my html

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
<div> </div>
</a>
```

my css

```
div {
    background:#f00;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:300px;
}

a {background:blue;}
```

the link actually works, but i see no blue `background` and chrome says that my `a` have no height and width

[image]

changing the css of the `a` to `display:inline-block` does the trick here, but not in my website.

[image]

do you have any suggestion or solution? how come the `a` element doesn't "follow" its child?
thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/72cYy/82/

Comment: If it works on jsFiddle but not on your site I'd guess that you have more CSS that you're not sharing that's causing a conflict.

Comment: it's not working on js fiddle without inline-block and i don't want to add inline-block to my links. i do have more css on my website but it goes down to that simple structure

Comment: do you by chance have a padding on your <a>'s? That way you'd still see the blue from the parent. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/72cYy/82/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why anchor tag does not take height and width of its containing element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585069/why-anchor-tag-does-not-take-height-and-width-of-its-containing-element)

Comment: @Vucko there's an <a> wrapping an img there. img are inline-block elements, not block elements like in this case

Comment: @vlrprbttst you're right - I'm retracting my vote. In FF seems to work thought.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you're looking for, you can set `a` to `display:block` if you want it to behave like a block element:

```
a {
   display: block;
   background:blue
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/72cYy/83/)

or you could set it to `display: inline-block` to make it behave like it natrually would:

```
a {
   display: inline-block;
   background:blue
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/72cYy/84/)

There is no reason that either of these wouldn't work on your site. Perhaps you have CSS or javascript overwriting it? Both of these methods will fix the collapsed height/width issue. If it is a conflicting CSS issue you could be more specific by adding an `id` or a `class`:

```
a#wrapper{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
a.wrapper{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

For more information on collapsed elements, you can check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585069/why-anchor-tag-does-not-take-height-and-width-of-its-containing-element/18586297#18586297)

Comment: yes i  know, i just expended the <a> to follow without having to specify a display behaviour

Comment: @vlrprbttst added a link of an SO post that explains this behavior