# How to make an a tag border wrap around an image

Tags: html, css

I need the border to be applied to the a tag but when I do this the border doesn't wrap around the image how can I make this happen?

```
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/17/41/javascript-736400_960_720.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

css:

```
a{
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b7qdcub1/

Comment: What has that fiddle got to do with anything?

Comment: Check your fiddle. It has wrong code.

Comment: The question and the fiddle do not correspond to the same problem.

Comment: you can set the border on image like this a img{border:5px solid blue;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know about **Why anchor tag does not take height and width of its containing element** [Read This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18586297/4786568).  Instead of border property I'm using [css outline](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp).

N.B: There are lots of technique  you can solve this  this.  like Set the border for img element or set display inline-block on anchor tag. Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swdtbppg/2/) for more solution

```css
div a{
outline:5px solid blue;
}
div a img{
 vertical-align:bottom; /* Need this to clear white-space */

}
```

```html
<div>
 <a href="#">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/17/41/javascript-736400_960_720.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply `display: block` to your `a` tag so that it behaves as a block level element. Also give it a fixed `width` and a `height` to encompass the image inside it.

Refer code:

```css
a {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  display: block;
  width: 720px;
  height: 720px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/17/41/javascript-736400_960_720.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to clip image to its bounds. Try this

```
a{
border: 5px solid blue;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    a{
  border: 5px solid blue;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put a border on the div.

```css
div {
border:solid;}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/17/41/javascript-736400_960_720.png">
  </a>
</div>
```