# Position:absolute; left property not working correctly

Tags: css, css-position, inline, absolute

In the following codepen - https://codepen.io/tanmaylodha/pen/MWKXJWW
CSS:Line-26; the `left:50%` is not working correctly.
But if I set `display:inline-block` on the containing block `.section-first a` of absolutely positioned element `.badge` then it works fine.

```
    <section class="section section-first">
   <a href="#">
     <h1 class="badge">Recommended</h1>
     <h1 class="plus-plan">Our PLUS Plan</h1>
     <h2>The most popular choice of our customers.</h2>
     <p>
       Benefit from increased storage and faster support to ensure that
       your mission-critical data and applications are always available!
     </p>
   </a>
 </section>

.section {
  color: #6c6164;
  background-color: #f7fafd;
  padding: 1.563rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.563rem;
  border: 5px solid #fca156;
  margin-right: 12.5rem;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 10px 2px #4fbf99;
}

.section-first {
  margin-top: 8rem;
}

.section-first a {
  position: relative;
}

.badge {
  font-family: "Red Hat Display";
  background-color: #60a7bd;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

.section h1.badge {
  color: white;
}

.section-first .plus-plan {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.section-highlighted {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 10px 2px #4fbf99, 5px 5px 10px 2px #60a7bd;
  text-align: right;
}

.section:hover {
  border-color: #ff943c;
}

.section a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Now check this codepen - https://codepen.io/tanmaylodha/pen/jOWKyZP
But here the results are different. `.child` being absolutely positioned element is getting correctly positioned after 50% width of its containing block `.parent`

```
 <a href="" class="parent">
  I am a Parent
  <div class="child">
    I am a child
  </div>
</a>

.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: chocolate;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  left: 50%;
}
```

In both the above Codepen, the containing block(being positioned relative) is always an inline element, then why the results are different?

Comment: Post your [mcve] here please -- not on codepen

Comment: But I have included necessary html and css only in the codepen.

Comment: I'm not sure I know the technical explanation, but the difference is that in the second example the <a> tag has some actual content ("I am a parent"). If you do the same in the first example, it should work. Also, it's important that this content is before the absolute positioned div. It also works if the first child of <a> is changed to an inline element.

Comment: So essentially, what difference is the text making in the appearance of the badge?
I mean why without text it will not be positioned after 50% of the parent container width form left?

Comment: @TanmayLodha ALSO post the necessary code here, not only in codepen.

Comment: @TanmayLodha as I said, I don't know the technical reason. I suspect it's something to do with a weird behaviour of block elements inside an inline element.

Comment: I have posted the necessary code here also, please check it out now.

Comment: You don't have any content in the anchor parent for the child to be positioned at 50% of.  Put a line of text and you will see "Recommended" move over as expected.  In your second pen, if you take out the text "I am a parent" then your child block will not be positioned where it is anymore

Comment: That's what I am asking exactly -  why without text it will not be positioned after 50% of the parent container width form left?
IS it because anchor tag width*height  = 0*0 because the content inside it is out of document flow and anchor tag being inline element (without any content) will take 0 width and 0 height.

Comment: because without content it has no width

Comment: But if I add a padding to anchor tag(no content still) then also child is getting positioned correctly.

Comment: Also, in the 1st case (or 1st codepen) anchor tag does have a width and height (not 0)
because h1,h2,p tags are also there in it.

Comment: the padding is giving the anchor width, and so `.badge` will be positioned at 50% of the padding.

Comment: Also, in the 1st case (or 1st codepen) anchor tag does have a width and height (not 0) because h1,h2,p tags are also there in it. then why it is not working in that case?

Comment: perhaps [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585069/why-anchor-tag-does-not-take-height-and-width-of-its-containing-element) will help you.  You need to set "inline-block" to the anchor

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question, after setting inline-block, it works. I don't need alternatives, I want the reason of why it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the issue more clear here is the minimal code that illustrate the difference:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="parent">
      I am a Parent
      <div class="child">
        I am a child
      </div>
    </a>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="" class="parent">
  <div>I am a Parent</div>
  <div class="child">
    I am a child
  </div>
</a>
```

Note how in the first case you have text content inside your inline element so your element is having a width used as reference for the left property. In the second case, you have a block element inside an inline element and this one is now having a width equal to `0` (no background coloration) and this is what you are facing in your first code. `left:X%` of `0` is `0` so nothing will happen.

What you are doing is of course valid but having block element inside inline element will make the rendring a bit tricky. From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level) you can read:

> When an inline box contains an in-flow block-level box, the inline box (and its inline ancestors within the same line box) **are broken around the block-level box** (and any block-level siblings that are consecutive or separated only by collapsible whitespace and/or out-of-flow elements), s**plitting the inline box into two boxes** (even if either side is empty), one on each side of the block-level box(es). The line boxes before the break and after the break are enclosed in anonymous block boxes, and the block-level box becomes a sibling of those anonymous boxes. When such an inline box is affected by relative positioning, any resulting translation also affects the block-level box contained in the inline box.

Yes not easy to understand but let's take our example and add more CSS to better see:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: chocolate;
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
some text before<br>
<a href="" class="parent">
  <div>I am a Parent</div>
</a>
<br> some text after
```

You can see how the block element broke our inline element in two *chunks* that are empty.

To avoid dealing with this, avoid having block element inside inline elements. Use `inline-block` to fix this issue:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: chocolate;
  border:2px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
some text before<br>
<a href="" class="parent">
  <div>I am a Parent</div>
</a>
<br>
some text after
```

Comment: but upon inspecting `.parent` its width is `1109px` (viewport width being `1125px`)
Then what's the issue, because it's width is not 0 in your 2nd case.

Comment: @TanmayLodha where did you inspect parent and got 1109px? technically you cannot do this because it's not more *one* element

Comment: inspect the a tag and then see its dimensions.

Comment: @TanmayLodha the tag has no dimension, as you can see there is no coloration on it. Did you read my full answer at the end? you cannot inspect the tag because it's not more *one* element

Comment: OK so then going to the elements tab and hovering over anchor tag `.parent` is showing the dimensions in the display window. what are these?

Comment: @TanmayLodha the browser will try to show something for you. If you try in different browser you may get different results but it's clear from the code that your element is having no width since the background is not applying. Also the specification is clear detailing what is happening.

Comment: Yeah, I have understood that!
But is there any way to send you screenshot to show what I am seeing regarding the dimensions.

Comment: @TanmayLodha the browser is giving you the width of the content inside so it's easy for your to see the layout but it's a bit missleading .. at least now you know that you should never use block element inside inline elements ;)

Comment: So in actual, that's not the width and height of anchor tag?

Comment: @TanmayLodha no it's not. You can also use JS to get the computed width/height and you will not get the same (you will get 0)

Comment: NO, I have used `console.log(document.getElementById('a').getBoundingClientRect());` (where #a is anchor tag )
and it is returning width:760px and height:159px.
Hence, not width not equals to 0.

Comment: @TanmayLodha no, this not the same. getBoundingClientRect will consider the element and its child ... I am not expert in JS to explain this very well but it's not exactly the same as getting the computed width which is the reference for the left property.

Comment: Yeah, clientWidth and clientHeight: is giving 0 width and height. That's why it was not working!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this...

```
.section-first {
  position: relative;
}
```

Instead of the below style.

```
.section-first a {
  position: relative;
}
```

The `<div>` tag is a block level element.
The `<a>` tag is tag is an inline element.

Comment: This is an alternative! my main concern is that why is it not working?