# Why doesn't <a> fill up <td> but it has width and height on 100%

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the problem that I want a table with links. I have an  as child from a  tag like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="https://app.netlify.com/sites/controllpanel-chraebsli/overview">Controllpanel</a></td>
        <td><a href="https://app.netlify.com/sites/controllpanel-chraebsli/deploys"><img src="https://api.netlify.com/api/v1/badges/db717d14-d6ee-42c3-ae0e-3eb748d705aa/deploy-status"alt="Netlify Status"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want that the first  fills up the  which I tried with this:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

That should fill the  with the  or not? On the picture below you can see that the  only has the size of the text (1). But you can also see that it has the CSS like I mentioned (3) and that the  is the child from  (2).

Then why doesn't >a> fill up ? And how can I fill fill it up that  has the same size as ?

[image]

Comment: Display it as `block`

Comment: anchor tags default to `display: inline`. make it `display: block`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the `<a>` tag by default is shown as `display: inline`, which doesn't respond to width and height CSS; you'd have to change it to `display: inline-block` which does.

Additionally, if your table cell has padding, and you want the `<a>` to fill it entirely, either remove the cell's padding or apply a negative margin to the anchor equal to the padding of the cell.

Comment: This question, unsurprisingly, has been asked many times before. If it seems like a question is quite simple, please help us by finding the original question, rather than answering

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tags are [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) by default. Set them to `display: block` and your problem is solved!

Comment: This question, unsurprisingly, has been asked many times before. If it seems like a question is quite simple, please help us by finding the original question, rather than answering.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry, i think that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585069/why-anchor-tag-does-not-take-height-and-width-of-its-containing-element) is the original question

Comment: Then flag the question as a duplicate of that post.